# Problem on othogonal polynomials with Lebesgue mesure

Tags: polynomials, orthogonality, orthonormal, approximation-theory, orthogonal-polynomials

This is an over my level assignmet i got:

Let $\mu$ denote the Lebesgue (of arc-length) measure on the unit circle $\mathbb{T}:=\{|z|=1\}$. Prove that for the measere

$dv(z)=|1-z|^{2}d\mu$

the monic polynomial of degree n orthogonal with respect to $v$ is

$P_{n}(z;v)=\frac{1}{n+1}\sum_{j=0}^{n}(j+1)z^{j}.$

Analyze the location and the behavior of the zeros of $P_{n}$.

..........................................

Here's what I've gotten so far:

$d\mu(z)=|z|=ds$ on $\mathbb{T}$, so:

$dz=ie^{i\theta}d\theta=izd\theta$ $\implies$ $ds=\frac{dz}{iz}$, thus

$dv(z)=|1-z|^{2}d\mu$  $\implies$ $ds=\frac{|1-z|^{2}dz}{iz}$.

Now, the entries for the Gram matrix are (having in consideration we are working on the unit circle):

$<z^{j},z^{k}>=\int_{\mathbb{T}}\overline{z^{j}}z^{k}dv(z)=\int_{\mathbb{T}}|1-z|^{2}\overline{z^{j}}z^{k}\frac{dz}{iz}=\frac{1}{i}\int_{\mathbb{T}}(1-z)\overline{(1-z)}z^{k-j-1}dz=$

$=-\frac{1}{i}\int_{\mathbb{T}}(2+z+\overline{z})z^{k-j-1}dz=-\frac{1}{i}\left(2\int_{\mathbb{T}}z^{k-j-1}dz+\int_{\mathbb{T}}z^{k-j}dz+\int_{\mathbb{T}}z^{k-j-2}dz\right)$.

So the integral equals:

- $4\pi$ if $k=j$,
- $2\pi$ if $k=j+1$,
- $2\pi$ if $k=j-1$,
- $0$ in other case

but this is not leading me to the answear. Its going towars something like:

$P_{n}(z;v)=\sqrt{\frac{\Delta_{n-1}}{\Delta_{n}}}z^{n}$, where $\Delta_{n}$ is the determinant of the $n\times n$ Gramm sub-matrix.

which is not the desired.

......

Here are some updates: the Gram matrix this way has $4\pi$ on the diagonal and $2\pi$ in the upper and lower diagonal, the determinant can be calculated by some very serious double induction, but its not leading to the solution.

After this I tried just prooving that the solution proposed is orthogonal in $\mathbb{C}$ with $dv$, by calculating $, which comes down to this integral:

$<p_{a}(z),<p_{b}(z)>=\frac{N}{K}\int_{\mathbb{T}}\sum_{}z^{terms}dz=\frac{N}{K}\sum_{}\int_{\mathbb{T}}z^{terms}dz=\frac{N}{K}\sum_{}\int_{\mathbb{T}}z^{-1}dz$ = I.

if $p_{a}(z),p_{b}(z)$ are indeed orthogonal, then I must be null, but its not clear, so I proceeded to calculate $<p_{1}(z),<p_{2}(z)>$:

$p_{1}(z)=\frac{1}{2}(1+2z)$

$p_{2}(z)=\frac{1}{3}(1+2z+3z^{2})$

$<p_{1}(z),<p_{2}(z)>=\int_{\mathbb{T}}\overline{p_{1}(z)}p_{2}(z)|1-z|^{2}dz=$

$=\frac{1}{6}\int_{\mathbb{T}}\overline{(1+2z)}(1+2z+3z^{2})\overline{(1-z)}(1-z)dz=\frac{-1}{6}\int_{\mathbb{T}}z^{-1}dz=-\frac{\pi}{3}\neq0$

This means the exercise was not correct.  Of course, this is never a good sign, so if you find any mistake in my work, please let me know.

Comment: Hi and welcome to the Math.SE. Your question appears as an isolated (possibly homework) problem: such kind of questions are poorly received. Help other user understand your commitment to the solution of the problem you pose by adding more context to it. For example, why is this question interesting for you? What did you tried and where did you stopped and why?

Comment: Thank you, I have edited the question, added some context and what I have tried to solve the problem.